# Open a jQuery ui dialog and display PHP Post response after form submit

Tags: php, jquery, dialog, form-submit

I have a jQuery based form which set a value of an hidden input field in a form. I retrieve this value after a form submit with php : $_POST['myinputvar'] (it's a generated url).

This retrieved var is an url to a XML file which I parse with SimpleXML function.

The goal is to display this result in a dialog box after the submission of the form and do my PHP stuff here

The code :

the jQuery to populate my input field :

```
        $('#myForm').submit(function() {
            $("input[name='field']").val(generatedUrl);
        });
```

The PHP :

```
if (isset($_POST['field']))
{
  $xml = simplexml_load_file($_POST['field']);
  print_r($xml);
}
```

The form :

```
<form action="http://www.mysite.com/index.php" id="myForm" method="post">
<input name="field" type="hidden" value='' /> 
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="ok" />
</form>
```

So how can I display my PHP part into a dialog box after submit?

Any help will be very appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Just a note on your PHP - if all you're trying to do in the if statement is check if there is incoming POST data - you can just use `if($_POST)` rather than checking if one of the variables is set..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it seems you don't use AJAX, you can do it that way as statued in [the doc](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) :

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
    });
</script>



<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p><?php echo $xml;?></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hell, so simply! Thanks a lot!